# Disable automatic selection of a row after as NSTableView is populated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have two NSTableViews populated with Core Data that are linked using bindings.  When a row is selected in NSTableView1, NSTableView2 is populated and the first row in it is selected.  I have registered the NSArrayController that corresponds to NSTableView2 with KVO on its selectionIndex.  This is so that when a row is selected in NSTableView2 a method is run.  My problem is that when a row is selected in NSTableView1 then the first row in NSTableView2 is selected triggering the method.  I would like it so that I can select a row in NSTableView1 and populate NSTableView2 without having a row automatically selected in NSTableView2.  How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That you are using Core Data is unimportant here. This is strictly a bindings issue.

Turn off "Avoids empty selection" on your array controller.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me Xcode 8.3.3.

I have clicked the Empty checkbox:

[image]